# Reverse for 'create_order' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django

I get this error on the homepage of my website:

`NoReverseMatch` at

Reverse for 'create_order' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['create_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']`

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('',views.home, name='home'),
  path('products/',views.products, name='products'),
  path('customer/<str:pk_test>/',views.customer, name='customer'),

  path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name='create_order'),
  path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updateOrder, name='update_order'),
  path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name='delete_order'),
]
```

Here is My views.py file:

```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.urls import reverse
   from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
   from .models import *
   from .forms import OrderForm

   def home(request):
       orders = Order.objects.all()
       customers = Customer.objects.all()
       total_customers = customers.count()
       total_orders = orders.count()
       delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
      pending = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()
      context = {'orders':orders, 'customers':customers, 'total_orders':total_orders, 
     'delivered':delivered, 'pending':pending}
      return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

 def products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html', {'products':products})

def customer(request, pk_test):
   customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test)
   orders = customer.order_set.all()
   context = {'customer':customer, 'orders':orders}
   return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)

def createOrder(request, pk): 
   customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
   form = OrderForm(initial={'customer':customer})
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = OrderForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render('/')
    
context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)

def updateOrder(request, pk):
  order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
  form = OrderForm(instance=order)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

  context = {'form':form}
  return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)

def deleteOrder(request, pk):
  order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)

  if request.method == "POST":
     order.delete()
     return redirect('/')
  context = {'item':order}
  return render(request, 'accounts/delete.html', context)
```

And here is the html where I call the 'create_order':

```
   <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}">Place Order</a>
```

And finally, the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\CMS\crm1\accounts\views.py", line 15, in home
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Installation\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 673, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'create_order' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['create_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']`
```

I have looked at other posts and haven't found anything that helped, and I just joined this project so I don't exactly know what the original programmer was trying to do here.

Comment: is this your complete views.py? if not, share the line where "reverse" is being used

Comment: Yes, this is my complete views.py file.

Comment: I haven't used the "reverse" anywhere so far.

Comment: this is the only one I used in html

Comment: you have shared only a single line of html, share some more lines above and below of that line

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple problem.

In the dahsboard.html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order' %}">Create Order</a>
```

is what cause this error.

If you comment it out like this

```
<!-- <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order'%}">Create Order</a> -->
```

It will still cause the same problem because it wrapped by HTML comment tags which comment out HTML tags but the Django tags are still in work. In order to comment out Django tags you need

```
{# Django tags #}
```

so you have to use both HTML comment tags and Django comment tags on the line

```
<!-- <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{#% url 'create_order'%#}">Create Order</a> -->
```

OR, In this project, you can just delete the whole line.

;););)

Answer (score 2):

Simple I had the same error.
you must have commented the create order button in dashboard.html.
Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi, I am still facing the same issue above the raised. the create order button is not disabled, checked everything unable to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this error are:

1. Wrong url name in your html code: `create_order` is ok
2. Missing arguments or keyword arguments: `customer.id` is ok
3. Check if you have defined a namespace in your URL configuration

What the original programmer trying to do is: When you're going to create an order, you fill the customer data with the current customer, maybe you have a table with customers and you have a button for create an order for this customer, for example:

```
<table>
    {% for customer in customers %}
    <tr> 
     <td>{{customer.name}} </td>
     <td> <a href="{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}">Order</a></td>
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

In the `createOrder` view you get the customer with `customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)` and with `initial` inside the form you declare the initial value of form fields at runtime

Comment: I haven't  defined any namespace in my url configuration.

Comment: Actually that's what I want to do, whatever you say. When I am going to create an order for the exact customer, it works and take to the form. From here when I submit the form or want to go the homepage, then it gives the NoReverseMatch error. Also normally when I run the server then the homepage doesn't open and shows the error.

Comment: In your `createOrder` view, when you check `form.is_valid()` and you save the form, you must `redirect` to the homepage not `render`.

Comment: I have already used redirect('/') but that didn't work.

Comment: you can put more lines of the html, specifically where you show the form

Answer (score 0):

The code is very collect despite the error, It means there is a line in a file where you used `{% url 'create_order' %}` without passing customer.id parameter ie.
`{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}` since in url.py you have this line:

```
path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name='create_order'),
```

and you have to  pass a parameter in `createOrder` which is the primary key which must be missing.

Answer (score -1):

The error is in the `order_form.html` : `{% url 'create_order' %}`
You've to correct this by adding : `{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}`

But first, remember passing the variable customer to your context when redering `order_form.html` : `{'customer': customer}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure that your solution was not already proposed in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794308/6682517) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699801/6682517) before posting it.